# arithmetic operation in cat eof with for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, cat

I'm trying to edit a line in cat eof script. The edited line should substract the iterated number from some constant inside the cat eof. i have tried donig it like this but with no result `10 - $i  | bc`
below is an example.

```
for i in $(seq 0.000  0.001 .01)
do
mkdir Doc"$i"
cat <<EOF > Doc"$i"/RUN.fdf
2.399 - $i |bc
2.444 - $i |bc
EOF

done
```

Comment: Add `$( )` around the things you want run as commands. That said, is there really a reason to use a heredoc here at all? You could just have `bc` write output direct to the file.

Comment: I have a much bigger data this is just an example, the only way to edit it is inside cat

Answer (score 0):

Add command substitution syntax -- `$( )` -- around the things you want treated as command substitutions.

```
for i in $(seq 0.000  0.001 .01); do
  mkdir Doc"$i"
  cat <<EOF >Doc"$i"/RUN.fdf
$(2.399 - $i |bc)
$(2.444 - $i |bc)
EOF
done
```

Comment: `seq 0.000  0.001 .01` outputs floating-point numbers using `LC_NUMERIC`, so it breaks with locale's `decimal_point=","`.  `for i in $(LC_ALL=C seq 0.000  0.001 .01); do` might be more reliable instead as all current implementations of `bc` only handles dot decimal.

Comment: I tried your solution but i keep getting this error
line 4: 2.444: command not found

Comment: @asemassaf you typically need to send the equation as a string to bc; try: `$(echo "2.399 - $i" | bc)`; alternatively you can remove one subprocess call with `$(bc <<< "2.399 - $i")`